# Formatting Issues

Tags: templating

I need help formatting my pages.  Right now the way my CMS is formatted, All the paragraphs of copy I put onto any given page get broken up into columns and it is very frustrating and I haven't a clue how to change it. Please help.

Comment: Dan, please add more specifics to your question so people can give a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a broad answer because it will be difficult to answer without knowing the specifics of how your site was built.  For more specific answers, I'd suggest getting in touch with the original developers of your site or whoever is in charge of maintaining it now.

Craft's templates (the things that make up the front of your site) will be in the `templates` folder on the server that Craft is installed on.  Your site's CSS, JavaScript, and assets will likely be in your public HTML folder on that same server.  You'll need access to them to make the modifications to your site it sounds like you want to make.

From there, you'll likely need to know a bit about how Craft works, particularly Craft templating.

Here's a collection of developer resources to help get you up to speed on Craft quickly.

**Craft Official Docs & Support**

- [Craft CMS docs](http://craftcms.com/docs)
- [Craft Discord](http://craftcms.com/discord) - Tons of Craft helpful . Craft developers and users from all over the world are there.
- [Craft StackExchange](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/) - You've obviously found this one, but this is the best place to ask "how do I" implementation type of questions.

**Learn Craft**

- [Mijingo Craft's Tutorials](http://mijingo.com/craft)
- [Tuts+ Tutorials](https://tutsplus.com/courses/search/Craft+CMS)
- [nystudio107 Blog](https://nystudio107.com/blog)